# Java bean validation uppercase letters with range

Tags: java, regex, validation, java-8, javabeans

I have a some issue with pattern for java bean validation.
I have a pattern for my variable inside java class

```
@Pattern(regexp = ".*[A-Z]+[[A-Z]\\p{Space}]+[A-Z\\p{Punct}]+([0-9]{1,10})?", message = "Error")*
private String name;
```

And actually it's working, but now I have to add a range {0,32} to uppercase words.
When I added [A-Z]{0,32} it breaks down

The ***name*** should fit values below

1. PROFILE - true
2. P - true
3. PRO - true
4. PROFILEPROFILEPROFILEPROFILEPROF - true
5. PROFILEPROFILEPROFILEPROFILEPROFI - false
6. profilename - false
7. PROFILE1 - true
8. PROFILE100 - true
9. PROFILE1000 - true
10. PROFILE1000000 - true
11. 1111 - false
12. PROFILEPROFILE123456789PROFILE123 - false
13. profile_name - false
14. *^^@ - false
15. PROFILE NAME - true
16. PROFILE_NAME - true
17. PROFILE. - true
18. &)12p - false
19. 11PROFILE - true
20. 1234PROFILE - true
21. $%#PROFILE - true
22. nothing - false

**How to change/refactor that pattern to possible to add range for uppercase letter and 2, 5, 12 would working?**

The solution is "(?=.*[A-Z])[\p{Punct}A-Z0-9 ]{1,32}"

Comment: What's the complete pattern?

Comment: Actually it's the complete pattern and it's working but when i want to add range for uppercase letter [A-Z]{0,32} it breaks
How to change/refactor that pattern to possible to add range for uppercase letter?

Comment: What do you mean by *adding range*?

Comment: I mean name should be min - 1 and max - 32 characters

Comment: The pattern, as you have posted, requires the matches to have at least three characters, so `P` won’t match. The trailing `([\\p{Upper}]+[0-9]{1,10})?` is completely obsolete, as, when it doesn’t match, the subsequent `.*` will accept everything anyway. And it doesn’t make much sense to use a generic `\\p{Upper}` class when you intend to restrict it to ASCII `[A-Z]` now. How is anyone supposed to help you, when you don’t even know yourself what you want?

Comment: Thanks, Holger for your reply! I'm new in regex and I understand you, right now it's difficult for me and i don't know what to do. I don't know how to add  letters range in that big pattern.

Comment: I've asked the forum help to modify that pattern to fit the conditions above

Comment: I've changed pattern because [\\p{Upper}] is obsolete but still have same problems

Comment: What are the requirements? The regex needs a complete re-vamping, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you, @Wiktor Stribiżew, for your question!
Yes you are right!

  1. Only capital letters
  2. The name must have length from 1 to 32
  3. The name can have #$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
  4 .The name must not have only #$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
  5. The name must not have lower case letters
  6. The name can start from numbers
  7. The name can finish with numbers
  8. The name can have space
  9. The name can be separated.

For better example in description i wrote what condition is true and what is false. I mean **true**  it's ok, **false** is not ok

Comment: Try `"(?=.*[A-Z])[\\p{Punct}A-Z0-9 ]{1,32}"` - https://regex101.com/r/XGk4AL/1

Comment: Excellent!!! Great!!! 
Thank you, thanks you, thanks, thank you very much!!!

Comment: I posted the answer. Next time please use `@`+username in your feedback comments so that the user knew of that feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
@Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[A-Z])[\\p{Punct}A-Z0-9 ]{1,32}", message = "Error")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XGk4AL/1%60)

Since the pattern is anchored by default (it is used with `.matches()` method), no `^` and `$` are necessary around the pattern.

It matches:

- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - after any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars there must be at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter
- `[\\p{Punct}A-Z0-9 ]{1,32}`  - match 1 to 32 uppercase ASCII letters, digits, space or chars from the Punct POSIX character class (it includes punctuation and symbols).